NgStyle background url doesnt apply style to html
I'm facing a problem when I'm trying to show image where the filename is having special characters like !23$%^&()image.png, the image wont be displayed because the style is not being applied,
  <div class="files border-t full_height" *ngFor="let file of files ; let last = last; let first = first">    
          <div class="files-container-preview">
            <div *ngIf="file?.Extension =='.jpg' || file?.Extension == '.jpeg' || file?.Extension== '.gif' || file?.Extension =='.png' || file?.Extension =='.svg' || file?.Extension =='.bmp' || file?.Extension =='.tif' || file?.Extension =='.tiff' || file?.Extension =='.webp'; then images else other">
            </div>
            <ng-template #images>
                <span class="attachment-container-preview-ext" *ngIf="file?.PreviewLink" 
                [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + file?.PreviewLink + ')'}">
              </span>
            </ng-template>
          </div>
      </div>


This is how the HTML is rendering this part when I add an image with special characters in the filename...
I have tried changing it to [style.background]="'url(' +  file?.PreviewLink + ')'"> and this doesn't work also, if I try to add the same image file renamed to something without special characters and spaces then the image is displayed.

Have you tried applying proper URL encoding to the value?

@C3roe the link that im passing is encoded already

Can you clarify which characters exactly are causing problems then? That 2 and 3 are actually among them, is rather hard to imagine. Because of the mention of % I assumed it could be an URL encoding issue - but perhaps it is rather an issue with characters that have special meaning in HTML?

@C3roe i noticed last night that the image filename is not properly being encoded so thats the problem

So does that mean you were able to fix it by now, or what are you saying?

yes its fixed now, thank you for pointing me in the right direction



<div class="files border-t full_height" *ngFor="let file of files; let last = last; let first = first">    
    <div class="files-container-preview">
        <div *ngIf="file?.Extension =='.jpg' || file?.Extension == '.jpeg' || file?.Extension== '.gif' || file?.Extension =='.png' || file?.Extension =='.svg' || file?.Extension =='.bmp' || file?.Extension =='.tif' || file?.Extension =='.tiff' || file?.Extension =='.webp'; then images else other">
        </div>
        <ng-template #images>
            <span class="attachment-container-preview-ext" *ngIf="file?.PreviewLink" 
            [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + encodeURIComponent(file?.PreviewLink) + ')'}">
          </span>
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</div>



Try this, hopefully this should resolve your issue as it will handle special chars, incase you're still facing issue try renaming your file by removing the special chars.
